# Adding dummy columns by iterating over rows in big pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame (X11) like this:

```
    dx1      dx2    dx3    dx4    
0   25041   40391   5856    0     
1   25041   40391   25081   5856  
2   25041   40391   42822   0     
3   25061   40391   0       0     
4   25041   40391   0       5856  
5   40391   25002   5856    3569
```

I want to create dummy column(s) for cell values like 25041,40391,5856 etc. So there will be a column 25041 with value as 1 or 0 if 25041 occurs in that particular row in any dxs columns. I am using this code and it works when number of rows are less. Final outcome is at bottom.

```
mat = X11.as_matrix(columns=None)
values, counts = np.unique(mat.astype(str), return_counts=True)

for x in values:
    X11[x] = X11.isin([x]).any(1).astype(int)
```

When number of rows are many thousands or in millions, it hangs and takes forever and I am not getting any result.

Then I started using this code:Suggested by @michaelg

```
colN_d = X11.columns.values

for column_name in colN_d:
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(X11[column_name])
    print(column_name, dummies)
    col_names_dummies = dummies.columns.values
    print(col_names_dummies)

    #then you can append new columns to the dataframe
    for i,value in enumerate(col_names_dummies):
        X11[value] = dummies.iloc[:,i]
```

This generates dummy columns but for those dummy variables which occur in multiple columns like 40391(occurs in dx1 and dx2), 0, 5856(occur in dx3 & dx4) it generates multiple dummies and overwrites the previous dummy column(s) generated by same name and hence I loose row values. Something like this:

```
dx1    25041  25061  40391
0      1      0      0
1      1      0      0
2      1      0      0
3      0      1      0
4      1      0      0
5      0      0      1
['25041' '25061' '40391']
dx2    25002  40391
0      0      1
1      0      1
2      0      1
3      0      1
4      0      1
5      1      0
['25002' '40391']
dx3    0  25081  42822  5856
0  0      0      0     1
1  0      1      0     0
2  0      0      1     0
3  1      0      0     0
4  1      0      0     0
5  0      0      0     1
[0 '25081' '42822' '5856']
dx4    0  3569  5856
0  1     0     0
1  0     0     1
2  1     0     0
3  1     0     0
4  0     0     1
5  0     1     0
[0 '3569' '5856']
```

The final result comes something like: This is not correct and does not meet my expectation

```
dx1     dx2     dx3     dx4     25041   25061   40391   25002   0   25081   
25041   40391   5856    0       1       0       1       0       1   0   
25041   40391   25081   5856    1       0       1       0       0   1   
25041   40391   42822   0       1       0       1       0       1   0   
25061   40391   0       0       0       1       1       0       1   0   
25041   40391   0       5856    1       0       1       0       0   0   
40391   25002   5856    3569    0       0       0       1       0   0
```

You can see that 40391 occurs in all rows therefore it should have 1 in all rows. But as above depicted, the program created two dummies with same name and last one was included in this. Whereas a UNION of both occurrence should suffice the requirements. Similarly for column '0'.

It should come like this:This is correct and output should be like this.

```
dx1     dx2     dx3    dx4  0   25002   25041   25061   25081   3569    40391   42822   5856
25041   40391   5856    0   0   0       1       0       0       0          1        0       1
25041   40391   25081  5856 0   0       1       0       1       0            1      0       1
25041   40391   42822   0   0   0       1       0       0       0           1       1       0
25061   40391   0       0   0   0       0       1       0       0          1        0       0
25041   40391   0    5856   0   0       1       0       0       0          1        0       1
40391   25002 5856   3569   0   1       0       0       0       1          1        0       1
```

Is there a way to create dummy columns efficiently with my requirements? 
Any idea how to improve the logic mentioned above?

Comment: What is the expected output for the sample data you provided?

Comment: Expected output will have 25041,40391,5856 etc as column names and 1 & 0 as their values of occurrences in a particular row